# Coding forward and backward slashes in tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I try send request like http://site.com/abc%2Fabc and it doesn't work (send status 400). How I understand tomcat doesn't accept encoded path separators for security reasons, but I don't know how to enable this coding. (I have found only option AllowEncodedSlashes for apache http server). Can you help me?

**UPDATE**

I fixed this trouble using tiny hack - before render replace all '/' characters on '|' and after reverse this characters on '/'

Comment: I had the same problem but I could not find this question on SO because I did not realize the problem was related to encoded slash. I saw a 400 status error with Tomcat 7 with an empty body response / without response, so that was what I looked for in google.  
I hope adding this comment with keywords may help people with the same problem find this question :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a Tomcat option to allow encoded path separators.

Set the CATALINA_OPTS env var to

```
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
```

This will allow encoded slashes.

Comment: Just a note, this feature is disabled by default because it is a security risk: see http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/11/02/best-practices-securing-apache-tomcat-7 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack

Comment: Note that to fix forward slashes you need org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH.  Such a shame tomcat decide to break HTTP , rather than fix the underlying security problem (%2F and %5C are perfectly valid in URLs)

Comment: note also that Tomcat will convert encoded backslash in a path into a forward slash

Comment: Hi, please where can I modify these parameters? THANKS

Comment: @JohnnySparow In general the method for setting environment variables will depend on your platform, but the [answer by user2335780](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16579783/174979) should work across platforms in this specific case.

Answer (score 7):

We can also add this entry
"org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true" in catalina.properties
to allow encoded slash in url.

---

And to allow backslash you have to set different properties. 
[Refer this url](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html)
for different configuration.

Answer (score 1):

To make this workable for my by editing $CATALINA_HOME\conf\server.xml

Old Value: `<Connector ... protocol="HTTP/1.1"... />`

New Value: `<Connector ... protocol="HTTP/1.1"... relaxedQueryChars='\ { } |' />`

I am using Tomcat 7.0.88

Comment: You sir deserve more upvotes. This is the only thing that worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in your `<Connector` in the `server.xml`?

Comment: Yes. I put URIEncoding="UTF-8" in server.xml. It's not work only with %2F.. for example %3A - ":" work.